# "Сверху вниз"

Tags: орфография

Как пишется "сверху вниз": через дефис или раздельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Сверху вниз" пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 1):

*Сверху вниз* пишется раздельно, потому что основа не повторяется, как, например, в слове *чуть-чуть*.

Answer (score 0):

Мне 65 лет, и я всю жизнь, как научили в 1960-х годах, так всегда и писал: "сверху-вниз" и "слева-направо",- через дефис (посмотрите наши книги, изданные в тот период - там именно так). Я и сейчас продолжаю так писать, и старые опытные корректоры не возражают, пропускают рукописи в печать с такими и подобными "устаревшими" конструкциями, потому что как и я, они тоже считают, что это грамотно. Довод, что дефис вставляется только при повторении слова, в данном случае считаю недействительным. И ранее относительно дефиса имелось это правило, и не только это, но именно такие сочетания, как "сверху-вниз" и "сине-зеленый" (последнее, по явному упущению, до сих пор пишется через дефис), всегда считались за многие десятилетия устоявшимся ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕМ - таким сильным исключением, что оно само по себе являлось правилом (куда его дели?). Видимо, современные влиятельные в русском языке особы сами учились с трудом, если считают, что молодые люди не в состоянии запомнить исключения, и упрямо продолжают упрощать правила русской орфографии - уже не по реально изменяющемуся состоянию языка (причина, которую они приводят себе в оправдание), а в угоду стремительно нарастающему и агрессивному маргинальному слою: "говорю как хочу, пишу как говорю". Все-таки, свобода, во всех смыслах,- это одно, а грамотность, которая может быть, как и свежесть осетрины, всего лишь в одном смысле,- это совершенно другое! Внедрение первого во второе граничит с сознательной диверсией против русского народа, а может быть, таковою и является. Я имею в виду далеко не только данный случай, он всего лишь один из огромного множества. И все же я придерживаясь более оптимистического мнения относительно новых поколений русских людей, надеюсь, что они сами не допустят окончательного искажения Русского языка, Великого и Могучего!

Comment: Мне 57 и я не помню, чтобы в шестидесятых учили писать через дефис. Возможно - до 56 г., когда был введен новый, ныне действующий орфографический свод. Хотя и в старых книгах такого не помню. Признаю, что специально не смотрел, ибо мне в голову просто не приходила идея с дефисом.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле единственный случай возможного испольхования дефиса в подобных примерах - использование в качестве определения, т.е. для характеристики не действия, а состояния, качества, свойства.

*Управленческая схема "сверху-вниз" представлена на рис. таком-то*

Обычно в таких случаях закавычивается.